# Return two dimensional vector efficiently

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a problem, how to return a large two-dimensional vector efficiently from a function.
My task is to read a large file and return a matrix data.

Design one:

```
 std::vector<std::vector<double> > loadMatrix(const char* fileName){
      //read file
      return matrix;
 }
```

This one is not efficient.

Design two:

```
 std::vector<std::vector<double> >& loadMatrix(const char* fileName){
      //read file
      return matrix;
 }
 //get some errors
```

I just wonder if there is an way to solve this problem.

Comment: Why do you say it's not efficient? Have you profiled with optimizations on?

Comment: First, _do not_ return a reference to a local object (it's not inefficient, it's UB). Second, if your compiler supports C++11, return by value. Otherwise consider using the swap trick. Either way, profile profile profile (before optimizing and after optimizing).

Comment: With C++11 the first will most likely be *moved* and not copied. For the second variant there is a risk of undefined behavior (if you return a reference to a local variable).

Comment: There is also a third alternative: Pass the "matrix" as a non-const reference argument to the function, and return a boolean success/failure indicator.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I try a large file, it is very slow. I google and find some posts, which says it is not efficient in first design.

Comment: @allen.lao is just the return that is slow, or the whole thing? Are you compiling with optimizations turned on?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I doubt it will be moved. The copy will most likely be elided completely, so no need to move anything.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I don't think i used any optimization.

Comment: @utnapistim could you give me the swap trick in detail or a link. thanks.

Comment: @allen.lao, see [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21279703/186997) below.

Answer (score 3):

Your first one, if the vector is created within the function, is actually undefined behavior. If the vector is created inside the function you can simply return it like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > loadMatrix(const char* fileName){
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > matrix;
    //read file
    return matrix;
}
```

The `matrix` object will be moved (or the copy will be elided), thanks to the [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (return value optimization).

Answer (score 0):

The swap trick involves swapping values instead of assignment, when you can afford to do a destructive copy:

original code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > loadMatrix(const char* fileName){
    //read file
    return matrix; // Uses RVO
}

// create copy of temporary object returned by loadMatrix
std::vector<std::vector<double> > result = loadMatrix("matrixfile");
```

swap trick:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > result;

result.swap(loadMatrix("matrixfile"));
```

The swap trick will swap pointers with the temporary. This will cause the temporary returned by `loadMatrix` to destroy an empty object (what was default-constructed in `result`) and `result` to receive the value without any deep copy or reallocation.

The swap trick is a fast solution to return-by-value before the C++11 move semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an opportunity, if your compiler doesn't support move semantics, you can also init you matrix in this function:

```
bool loadMatrix(const char* fileName, std::vector<std::vector<double> > & matrix)
{
    // shows if something went wrong
    bool returnFlag = true;

    // read file and init matrix 
    return returnFlag;
}

// create matrix
std::vector<std::vector<double> > matrix;
if (true == loadMatrix("matrixfile", matrix))
{
    // do something
}
```

In this case no matrix copy will be performed.